# VBA UDF for color cells

Tags: vba, excel

I'm sure my question is simple to most of you as I'm new to UDF.  I've created the following UDF but cannot apply it across columns when I use =CheckColor1(H13:M13)

```
Function CheckColor1(range)
    If range.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 176, 80) Then
        CheckColor1 = "Final"
    ElseIf range.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0) Then
        CheckColor1 = "Final"
    ElseIf range.Interior.Color = RGB(191, 191, 191) Then
        CheckColor1 = "Final"
    ElseIf range = 0 Then
        CheckColor1 = "Final"
    Else
        CheckColor1 = " "
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Not sure if it relevant to your question, but here are two words of caution: a) Range.Interior.Color will not return a color set by conditional formatting; b) While Range.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color returns a correct color set by conditional formatting, you cannt use it in worksheet function (like =CheckColor1(H13:M13)). Just in case you were using Conditional formatting...

Comment: @Marek Stejskal yes, very true.  Why do you think it doesn't work in a UDF though? Is there some logic?

Comment: @CoolBlue I found it directly in MSDN documentation (search for Range.DisplayFormat Property), so it is probably by design. If there is some logic, I don't see it.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to define your function's argument object or data type.

According to the syntax for procedural parameters, much like declaring variables, you must use the "As" to specify the type of your argument.

The argument must be declared as a normal variable, omitting the Dim keyword.

You cannot, however, use the name of the data or object type as the argument name itself which was what you were trying to do.

```
Function CheckColor1(r as Range)
    If r.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 176, 80) Then
        CheckColor1 = "Final"
    ElseIf r.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0) Then
        CheckColor1 = "Final"
    ElseIf r.Interior.Color = RGB(191, 191, 191) Then
        CheckColor1 = "Final"
    ElseIf r.interior.colordindex = 0 Then
        CheckColor1 = "Final"
    Else
        CheckColor1 = " "
    End If
End Function
```

[image]

Comment: Very interesting........does the function test **all** the cells in a range or only a single cell in that range??

Comment: It tests all the cells I suppose?

Comment: @Gary's Student interestingly, the .Interior.Color property will return 0, if the cells do not all have the same color, or the RGB value of the color if they are all the same.  It will also return 0 if all of the cells are black.

Comment: @JLILI Aman the code will error if it gets to the r = 0 test.

Comment: Corrected that @CoolBlue

Comment: The op did not make her question clear. I would provided a better answer @MarekStejskal.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to add the comment to the OP, not to the answer, I'll delete it.